# Why am I not able to receive output when running python code in VSCode?

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I have tried to print simple messages like "Hello World!" but have always been met with: [Running] python -u "/Users/user/HelloWorld!!/app.py"
/bin/sh: python: command not found

[Done] exited with code=127 in 0.176 seconds
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCn1R.png)

Is there any way to get passed this error?

Answer (score 0):

**Check environment variable PATH**

Every time you as a user run a command on your console, the machine looks for its location, or address, inside a list of predefined directories that are stored inside the environment variable PATH.

Such design helps to properly run the program or command without having to specify the absolute path on the terminal.

The environment variable PATH can be modified temporarily for the current terminal session, or permanently.

[For windows/mac/linux](https://gist.github.com/nex3/c395b2f8fd4b02068be37c961301caa7)

AND

Go to the VS Code preferences, and under interpreter, you'll find Interpreter Path, so set that to the path of your python installation, restart VS Code, and you should be good.